# How to run PowerShell core commands in bash script directly?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, powershell-core

I mostly use `Az CLI` commands in `bash` scripts to manage `Azure` resources. Sometimes, I need to utilize the `PowerShell core` commands as the `Az CLI` versions do not exist.

I want to use both `Az CLI` and `PS core` commands in a `bash` shell together. I mean, I'd like to have `only one` bash script and execute all required commands in it.

Do you know a way to run `PowerShell core` commands **directly** in a bash script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. however you can use powershell for linux (pwsh) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7

e.g. from bash you can call this program and pass the command

```
$ pwsh -c "write-host Hello world"
Hello world
```

Comment: You don't understand what Powershell Core is. What you call "powershell for linux (pwsh)" is **precisely Powershell Core**. Your very own link even contains the name in the url... Powershell Core is the cross-platform version of Powershell that provides the `pwsh` executable for all platforms.

Comment: On some linux shells double quotes did not work but single quotes did: `pwsh -c '$a=1; echo "a is $a";echo "b is $env:b";Get-host;'`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute multiple commands with single pwsh call in bash (for me, only single quotes worked on ubuntu bash shell. Double quotes or curly braces`{}` did not work):

```
pwsh -command '$a=1; echo "a is $a"; echo "b is $env:b"; Get-host;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would call a PowerShell script from inside bash if need to execute a number of commands but if you just want to execute one you can run pwsh -command COMMAND
Example:
pwsh -command get-childitem